# Filtering out admins from members in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app where users are approved by an admin after registering. I need a little help filtering out the admins in the members list.

This is my index method:

```
def index
  if params[:is_approved].to_i == 0
    @users = User.find_all_by_is_approved(0) #returns all unapproved users
  else
    @users = User.find_all_by_is_approved(1) #here I wanna filter out the admins
  end   
end
```

I tried to add `&& User.find_all_by_is_admin(0)` but then I get all the users that are not admins, i.e., the unapproved users.

Admins are users but have a column `is_admin` set to true, and I dont want to display them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the list of users who are approved but aren't admins:

```
User.where(:is_approved => 1, :is_admin => 0)
```

or if you want to write it in the style you were using you could do:

```
User.find_all_by_is_approved_and_is_admin(1, 0)
```

The reason why what you're trying isn't working is because `&&` is the boolean AND operator so if you write

```
User.find_all_by_is_approved(1) && User.find_all_by_is_admin(0)
```

Both sides of the `&&` here are considered true so this evaluates to the right-hand side i.e. `User.find_all_by_is_admin(0)`

There is an `&` (single & sign) operator on arrays in Ruby that gives the *intersection* of 2 arrays i.e.

```
User.find_all_by_is_approved(1) & User.find_all_by_is_admin(0)
```

would be the list of users who are in both lists, but this is an inefficient way of doing it as it results in 2 separate database queries.

Comment: Thanks Mike, im quite new to rails and this helped a lot :D

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. The `User.where..` style is the Rails 3 way of doing querying. You can find out more about what you can do with it in  [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3).